# Adding a category column to in an excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, categories

I have a dataset in excel in which one column has list of companies. The list is transport companies, vendors, hospital etc. Now I want to insert another column next to it where I write vendor in front of vendors company, transport in front of transport companies and so on. I don't want to do data validation list. Vlookup doesn't work because then I have to manually create the list at firstly.

Is there a way to do this action?

Comment: Question is not clear.  You may show what you tried, at least in a screenshot.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want Excel to recognize a company type purely from the company name. If that's the case, than it's not possible to automate this, but without sample data it's hard to tell if there's a way (or to see if there's a different column holding usable info).